# Passing a parameter into a Javascript method

Tags: javascript, methods

I have the following code:

```
function isFieldEmpty(input)
        {   
            if(document.frmRegister.input.value == "")
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I call it using isFieldEmpty("fieldName"). However, I think the "input" bit is incorrect...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is looking for a property literally called `"input"` on `frmRegister`. To look for `"fieldName"` for example (the *value* of `input`), you want bracketed notation:

```
if(document.frmRegister[input].value == "")
// Change -------------^-----^
```

In JavaScript, you can access the property of an object using either dot notation and a *literal* property name (`obj.foo`) or using bracketed notation and a *string* property name (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the property name string can be the result of any expression, including a variable or argument lookup.

Comment: Not only did you solve my problem; but you explained around the problem so I now understand. Cheers! (I will accept in 7 minutes)